# How to get to the bottom of Dungeon Destard in Ultima 5 Lazarus

Tags: ultima-5-lazarus

In Dungeon Destard, I get from a cave environment to a stone wall hall with Ettins and Trolls, but cannot find a way to go down further. Is this the right way to go? I can see a corridor on the other side of the wall, but cannot blow the stone wall up. I don't see hidden lever either.

I searched Google and I don't see anything about "lazarus destard".

[image: Destard Dead End]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a button, that is well hidden, in a side room to your image.

Spoiler:

> There are some walls that can be "attacked" to break them down.  Inside these walls, are water troughs.  The button is in a water trough.

From: http://www.projectbritannia.com/forum/index.php?topic=621.0

Comment: Can you summarize the contents of the linked thread, in case the linked forum ever disappears?

Comment: I didn't include it before because it was a bit spoilerish.  I figured out the spoiler markup, and edited the post to include the detailed answer.

Comment: Special thanks for your effort to spoilerize it :-)